# Factorising a complex polynomial over C

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

If $f(z)=z^3+7z^2+16z+10$, find all factors of $f(z)$ over $C$. If I had at least one zero or factor I would be able to find the others, but I just don't know how to start.

Comment: $z=-1$ works. With cubics, it is a good idea to check for rational roots by using the Rational Roots Theorem. Not a good idea for real world cubics, but handy for the artificial world of exercise cubics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $f(-1) = 0$. So $(z + 1)$ is a factor. The rest is easy.

Comment: What I don't understand is how one determines that in any other similar situation. Does one just arbitrarily pick integers until one finds a zero?

Comment: You could use the rational root theorem to guess and test some possible rational roots (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)